# Maximum number of decimals in R

Tags: r, formatting, decimal

How can I cut the decimals of a quotient in R? I'm computing millions of values and write them in a file on the fly. To save some space I don't want more than five decimals and also omit trailing zeros.

I tried

```
options(digits=5)
```

which I read only is a suggestion to R and doesn't work quit well. And

```
format(x, nsmall = 5)
```

determines only the minimum number of decimals. And

```
sprintf("%.5f", x)
```

will give me exactly five decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about with just

```
round(x,5)
x=1.23456777
round(x,5)
#[1] 1.23457
x=1.230000
#round(x,5)
[1] 1.23
```

If you don't want rounding try this:

```
as.integer(x*10^5)/10^5

x=1.234567777
as.integer(x*10^5)/10^5
#[1] 1.23456
x=1.230000
as.integer(x*10^5)/10^5
#[1] 1.23
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like to have the precision of exactly five decimals when necessary. The round method will behave a little different and the output for the first x wouldn't be 1.23457 but 1.2346

Comment: @Wipster Are you looking for `signif`?

Comment: ok, updated as per your requirement. I guess you want 1.23456 for 1.234567777 right?

Comment: as @Roland said are you looking for 5 decimal places or 5 significant figures?

Answer (score 1):

The round function works just fine if you refrain from changing the digits option beforehand.

Run with the default options:

```
> round(x = 1.23456777, digits = 5)
[1] 1.23457
```

Run with changed options:

```
> options(digits=5)
> round(x = 1.23456777, digits = 5)
[1] 1.2346
```

Comment: P.S.: The default value of digits is 7 (`getOption("digits")`)